# defining a function with specific parameters

Tags: python

I am tasked with defining a function that is given a string as an input and returns the string back again but edited with the following parameters listed below. My first lines of code all work and edit the string properly but I am unsure how to satisfy the last condition involving strings that include '@'

Noises for text analysis are defined as words that are not useful in the analysis, so we will remove them also. Write a function `cleaning_noise(sentence)` which takes an input parameter sentence (type string), and returns a string that has all noises removed from sentence. Noises are defined as follows:

- Words containing the character sequence 'http' should be removed wherever it appears in the sentence (whether it be itself or embedded in a word).
- The newline character (i.e., '\n') should be removed wherever it appears in the sentence.
- Words containing the character '#' should be removed wherever it appears in the sentence.
- Replace character sequence '&amp' with just '&' wherever it appears in the sentence.

Character '@' indicates mentions in tweets, and limiting mentions improved language model uses. In this assignment, we will simply remove every odd mentions found in the given sentence.

My code so far reads as follows however for the last condition involving @ it doesn't provide the right output

```
def cleaning_noise(sentence):
    out = sentence.split()
    final = []
    outcome = []
    result = []
    list1 = []
    for i in out:
        if ('http' or '\n') not in i:
            final.append(i)
    for num in final:
        if '#' not in num:
            outcome.append(num)
    for val in outcome:
        if '&' in val:
            result.append('&')
        elif '&' not in val:
            result.append(val)
    for i in result:
        if '@' in i:
            list1.append(i)
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            list1.remove(list1[i])
    return " ".join(finall)

simple_sentence = cleaning_noise("There is this &amp that &amp those.")
print(simple_sentence)


There is this & that & those.

simple_sentence = cleaning_noise("https://www.helloword.com is a random site. #random #site @randomguy @randomguy2")
print(simple_sentence)`

is a random site. @randomguy2
```

My output for this is wrong and returns only @randomguy2

Comment: Please look at your post after hitting the "post" button, and look at whether the markup you went with makes sense. Because right now, it really doesn't: write a normal text that introduces your problem instead of six consecutive quote blocks without any introduction.

Comment: sorry ive edited it and hopefully it now makes more sense

Comment: This is a little harsh. Its not that they have not put effort. They just used the quote block wrongly whcih you have rightly mentioned. The question is still readable. @NatashaBoshard Remove the quote blocks and add them as normal text.

Comment: thankyou, is this better?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing 5 separate loops!  Just process the list of words once.  You can keep a tweet counter to help you know how many @ words you have seen.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment doesn't make clear whether you need to remove '&amp' if it occurs INSIDE a word (like `left&ampright`).  This does not do so.

```
def cleaning_noise(sentence):
    final = []
    tweets = 0
    for word in sentence.split():
        word = word.replace('\n','')
        if 'http' in word:
           continue
        if '#' in word:
           continue
        if word == '&amp':
            word = '&'
        if '@' in word:
            tweets += 1
            if tweets % 2 == 1:
                continue
        # If we got this far, add to the output.
        final.append( word )
    return " ".join(final)
```